# Call an outgoing number using asterisk

Tags: asterisk, voip, asteriskami

I have an ATA connected to my hardline. I am trying to setup an API that will use AMI to allow my user to press a button, and make a call to a given cellphone number, and then play an audio to it.

I have been able to place calls to my cellphone by dialing the number from a softphone, which then dials to the ATA. However, I'd like to be able to do this without a softphone required for dialing; in other words "automate".

Answer (score -1):

1. Use click2call script(easy searchable)

https://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+click+to+call

2. Check intercom/autoanswer features on your phone and change dialplan for phone's leg to do AA.

https://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Paging+and+Intercom